# Elasticsearch indexing timestamp-field fails

Tags: elasticsearch, curl, timestamp, kibana

I fail at indexing timestamp fields with ElasticSearch (version 7.10.2) and I do not understand why.

So I create an index with the following mapping. You can copy & paste it directly to Kibana:

```
PUT /my-dokumente
{
    "mappings" : {
      "properties" : {
        "aufenthalt" : {
          "properties" : {
            "aufnahme" : {
              "properties" : {
                "zeitpunkt" : {
                  "type" : "date",
                  "format": "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss",
                  "ignore_malformed": true
                }
              }
            },
            "entlassung" : {
              "properties" : {
                "zeitpunkt" : {
                  "type" : "date",
                  "format": "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss",
                  "ignore_malformed": true
                }
              }
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
}
```

Then I try to index a document:

```
PUT /my-dokumente/dokumente/1165963
{
    "aufenthalt" : 
    {
        "aufnahme" : 
        {
            "zeitpunkt" : "2019-08-18 15:02:13"
        },
        "entlassung" : 
        {
            "zeitpunkt" : "2019-08-20 10:29:22"
        }
    }
}
```

Now, i get this error:

```
"mapper [aufenthalt.entlassung.zeitpunkt] cannot be changed from type [date] to [text]
```

Why is elastic search not parsing my date?

I also tried with **many** different mapping settings like `strict_date_hour_minute_second` or to send the timestamp as `"2019-08-18T15:02:13"` or `"2019-08-18T15:02:13Z"` also, I converted it to epoch millis, but I always get some different error message, for example `Cannot update parameter [format] from [strict_date_hour_minute_second] to [strict_date_optional_time||epoch_millis]`.

So the basic question is just: **How can I send a timestamp value to ElasicSearch?** (with Kibana/CURL).

PS: I am **not** using a Client SDK like Java High Level Rest Client. Why are talking about basic Kibana/CURL.

It can't be that complicated. What am I missing?

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Mapping types are removed in 7.x. Refer to this [official documentation](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/removal-of-types.html)**

You need to add _doc in URL when indexing a document to Elasticsearch

Modify the URL as `PUT /my-dokumente/_doc`

Comment: Oh my god. I was looking at the wrong place all the time. Thank you so much!!!